# the content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: json, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

When using firebug, I got this wired error "NetworkError: 415 Cannot process the ...xt/xml; charset=utf-8'. - `http://localhost:59899/wsccc1/wscccService.svc/RunTts`" in my asp.net mvc 4 project.

The code:

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ttsFunction() {
        serviceUrl = "http://localhost:59899/wsccc1/wscccService.svc/RunTts";
        var data = new Object();
        data.text = $('#speak').val();
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: serviceUrl,
            data: jsonString,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() { alert('ok')},
            error: function (xhr,status,error) {
                console.log("Status: " + status);
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                console.log("xhr: " + xhr.readyState);
            },
            statusCode: {
                404: function() {
                    console.log('page not found');
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The service code:

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class wservice:Iwservice
{
    public string RunTts(string value)
    {
        return value.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

The interface is:

```
namespace service
{
     [ServiceContract]
     public interface Iwservice
     {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "RunTts")]
        string RunTts(string text);
     }
}
```

And web config, I used file-less in WCF.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment >
       <serviceActivations>
         <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" 
     relativeAddress="./wsccc1/wscccService.svc" 
     service="service.wservice"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
   <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is the `wsservice` class on the `service` namespace? If not, it won't match the service activation.

Comment: Yes, I didn't type it in the code. When I typed http://localhost:59899/wsccc1/wscccService.svc in the browser, it does work.

Comment: Are you missing webHttpBehavior?

Comment: It is not in the web.config? Do I have to manually add it and how/where?

Comment: Yes. And I believe you have not defined the service endpoints. Based on what you are accessing you should have a webHttpBinding configured for this service & this endpoint should have an endpoint behavior which has <webHttp /> defined under it. The reason it throws this error may be you are trying to access a SOAP endpoint (default endpoint) like a REST endpoint.

Comment: Can you please provide an answer for it? I need code. The service is a class library file, I don't have a svc file as I used file-less in WCF 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `WebServiceHostFactory`, instead of the regular `ServiceHostFactory` in your code. That will configure the endpoint with the appropriate binding (`webHttpBinding`) and behavior (`webHttp`) to honor the `[WebInvoke]` attribute.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment >
   <serviceActivations>
     <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
          relativeAddress="./wsccc1/wscccService.svc" 
          service="service.wservice"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Comment: then in my case, I have the same problem and I only get it when trying to make calls to my service from jquery.  How come I don't have WebServiceHostFactory yet it's worked fine withmaking the same type of callls via Fiddler as I use that to also test?

Comment: var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://bschoolapp.azurewebsites.net/Service1.svc",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "soapAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetAnswers",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "5ea26881-e357-4501-a503-3e907ad1448d"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\"queNumber\":\"5\",\"answer\":\"sample answer\",\"studentID\":\"11111\"}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});

Answer (score 4):

Go to your web.config endpoint tag and check if `bindingConfiguration` is properly present or not and also make sure the address is spelled correctly.

```
<endpoint address="/YourName".../>
```