# Ajax not calling WCF service

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wcf

I have hosted a service sucessfully on IIS.

Made sure that application is running.

I have given call to this service through ajax as:

```
 var parameters = {

            'EmailID':EmailID,
            'Password':Password
            };

           $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:85/MobileECommerceTesting/Service1.svc/validateLogin",
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function (Data) {
               alert("asdsad");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error in Saving.Please try later.");

            }
        });
```

But its not giving call to the service.

What can be the problem?

**EDIT:**

[image]

**EDIT2 :**

Network Tab:

[image]

Comment: What actually does happen? Do you get the error alert? Is the request never made? If a request is made, can you screenshot the browser development F12 console network view for the request?

Comment: @JarekPiórkowski yes i get error alert...everytime it goes in error block

Comment: Alright, please post the response that ASP.NET is sending (find it in F12 -> Network). Or check IIS logs for any errors or exceptions.

Comment: @JarekPiórkowski I am using it through Phonegap.. not asp.net .. no error in console.. see my edit

Comment: @CuteChild Switch to the "Network" tab, reload to make it detect the request, and click into the request to see the details, particularly the Response information.

Comment: @JarekPiórkowski yeah, its error in network tab...(Edit2)

Comment: if you click on the entry for the request, it will show you the details of the request.

Comment: Can you post the configuration of your service ? The error is Unsupported Media Type. It might be related to your service binding and encoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

[the content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534010/the-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-was-not-the-expected-type-te)

It might be related to your binding, which does not expect the content type application/json. You must use webHttpBinding to create "REST-like" services with WCF.