# how to POST with jquery to WCF

Tags: jquery, html, .net, wcf

I have a problem with calling a WCF service from jquery. The error I am getting is

> 415 Cannot process the message because the content type
>   'application/json; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8'.

**Service1.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public string Authenticate(string data)
    {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

**IService1**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "auth")]

    string Authenticate(string data);

}
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TestServiceLibrary.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TestServiceLibrary.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tests = "test";
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "http://localhost/TestService/Service1.svc/auth",
                data: '{"data": "' + tests + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: true,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('success');
                 }
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to also set the following arguments for this method with no luck

```
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
```

Comment: Did you see this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17534969/903324 ?

Comment: adding the following had no affect      <serviceHostingEnvironment >
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
             relativeAddress="./Service1.svc"
             service="service.service1"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "auth")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you host the service make sure your svc looks like

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
```